# while refresh page getting code already redeemed - using google calendar API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

This is my code, its working fine. but if refresh a page, getting 400 error.

and log shows code already redeemed. please suggest where is error. I used refresh token also even though getting error.

refresh token correctly used?

Thanks

```
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);  //create user session

    try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        //String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
        String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
        String code = req.getParameter("code");
        String eventid = req.getParameter("eventid");
        if(eventid != null)
        session.setAttribute("eventid", req.getParameter("eventid"));


        GoogleTokenResponse response=null;

        Credential credential=null;


        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Collections.singleton(scope)).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();


        if(code == null){
        String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID,REDIRECT_URI,Collections.singleton(scope)).setState("").build();

        resp.sendRedirect(authorizationUrl);
        }else{


        response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .execute();
            // End of Step 2



            flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);

        }


            // Step 2: Exchange


            if(session.getAttribute("refresh") != null){


                credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                        .build().setFromTokenResponse((new TokenResponse().setRefreshToken(session.getAttribute("refresh").toString())));

                credential.refreshToken();


            }else{

                credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build().setFromTokenResponse(response);




                session.setAttribute("refresh", credential.getRefreshToken());


            }

            Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Minutes Of Meeting").build();

            List<CalEvent> lstEvent = new ArrayList<CalEvent>();

            Date d1=  getRelativeDate(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            String pageToken = null;
            do {
                Events events = service.events().list("primary").setTimeMin(new DateTime(d1,TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
              List<Event> items = events.getItems();
              for (Event event : items) {
                //System.out.println("Event Name: " + event.getSummary() + " Event Organiser :"+event.getOrganizer()+" Event Guest"+event.getAttendees());
                //lstEvent.put(event.getSummary(),event.getSummary());
                //lstEvent.put(event.getOrganizer().getDisplayName(),event.getOrganizer().getDisplayName());
                  if(event.getStart().isEmpty()){

                      List attees = event.getAttendees();


                      lstEvent.add(new CalEvent(event.getId(),event.getSummary(),event.getOrganizer().getDisplayName(),event.getLocation(),"","",attees));


                  }else{
                      Long dt = event.getStart().getDateTime()==null?0:event.getStart().getDateTime().getValue();
                      Date dt11 = new Date(dt);

                      Long dt1 = event.getEnd().getDateTime()==null?0:event.getEnd().getDateTime().getValue();
                      Date dt111 = new Date(dt1);

                      List attees = event.getAttendees();


                      lstEvent.add(new CalEvent(event.getId(),event.getSummary(),event.getOrganizer().getDisplayName(),event.getLocation(),dt11.toString(),dt111.toString(),attees));


                  }
                  //Date returnd = new Date(dt11.getTime()+(330*60000));

                  //Date returned = new Date(dt111.getTime()+(330*60000));

              }
              pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
            } while (pageToken != null);

            req.setAttribute("events", lstEvent);

            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp");
               try {
                rd.forward(req, resp);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

please help me solve this issue